# Rails 3 - how to make ternary condition in view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox, ternary-operator

I have ternary operator and I am trying this ternary operator put into checkbox, but I am still making fault in writing (syntax error)...

So I would like to ask about help, how to do...

```
CAR: <%= f.check_box :car, :value => 2, ((f.sex == 2) ? (:checked => true) : (:checked => false)) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a ternary operator here. Try this instead:

`CAR: <%= f.check_box :car, :value => 2, :checked => (f.sex == 2) %>`

Also your problem comes from the fact that in a `Hash` literal you can't define keys conditionally, so:

`{:a => (:b || :c)}` is valid

`{:b ? (a: => :b) : (:a => :c)}` is invalid

Answer (score 1):

`<%= f.check_box :car, :value => 2, :checked => f.sex == 2 ? true : false %>` will work, but can be shortened to `<%= f.check_box :car, :value => 2, :checked => f.sex == 2 %>`!